# problem using 'as_json' in my model and 'render :json' => in my controller (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to create a unique json data structure, and I have run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

In my controller, I am doing:

```
favorite_ids = Favorites.all.map(&:photo_id)
data = { :albums => PhotoAlbum.all.to_json,
         :photos => Photo.all.to_json(:favorite => lambda {|photo| favorite_ids.include?(photo.id)}) }

render :json => data
```

and in my model:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  { :name => self.name,
    :favorite => options[:favorite].is_a?(Proc) ? options[:favorite].call(self) : options[:favorite] }
end
```

The problem is, rails encodes the values of 'photos' & 'albums' (in my data hash) as JSON twice, and this breaks everything...  The only way I could get this to work is if I call 'as_json' instead of 'to_json':

```
data = { :albums => PhotoAlbum.all.as_json,
         :photos => Photo.all.as_json(:favorite => lambda {|photo| favorite_ids.include?(photo.id)}) }
```

However, when I do this, my :favorite => lambda option no longer makes it into the model's as_json method..........  So, I either need a way to tell 'render :json' not to encode the values of the hash so I can use 'to_json' on the values myself, or I need a way to get the parameters passed into 'as_json' to actually show up there.......

I hope someone here can help...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I gave up...  I solved this problem by adding my own array methods to handle performing the operations on collections.

```
class Array

  def to_json_objects(*args)

    self.map do |item|
      item.respond_to?(:to_json_object) ? item.to_json_object(*args) : item
    end

  end

end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_json_object(options = {})
    {:id => self.id, 
     :name => self.name,
     :is_favorite => options[:favorite].is_a?(Proc) ? options[:favorite].call(self) : !!options[:favorite] }
  end
end

class AssetsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @favorite_ids = current_user.favorites.map(&:asset_id)

    render :json => {:videos => Videos.all.to_json_objects(:favorite => lambda {|v| @favorite_ids.include?(v.id)}),
                     :photos => Photo.all.to_json_objects(:favorite => lambda {|p| @favorite_ids.include?(p.id)}) }

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think running this line of code

```
render :json => {:key => "value"}
```

is equal to

```
render :text => {:key => "value"}.to_json
```

In other words, don't use both `to_json` and `:json`.

Comment: But... I need the actual object to be json.  {:foo => @foo.to_json} does not mean that is a json object.  It means it's a ruby hash with a value that is encoded in json....

Comment: Can't you just use `render :text => json_object`?

Comment: I don't have a json object.  That's the problem.  How do I convert {:foo => "{\"json_foo\":\"json_foo\"}" }  Which is PARTLY json into  "{\"foo\":{\"json_foo\":\"json_foo\"}}" which would be a PURE json object...  That's the problem.

Comment: Besides, what you said is inaccurate anyway..  Even if you do render :text =>  "{\"foo\":{\"json_foo\":\"json_foo\"}}", an ajax response object from that will not be recognized as json, it will be seen as text and require being converted..  So the bottom line is, to get this to work will require lots of hacks on both the controller and javascript level.